# What is the Laplace transform of $e^{3t} \cdot \sin^2 t$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, laplace-transform

I am trying to compute the Laplace transform of the following functions $e^{3t} \cdot \sin^2 t$

Please help me to find a  solution

Comment: You seem to have lost the picture. Alternatively, it probably looks better and is easier to read if you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and format what you've tried directly.

Comment: Sorry i can't upload the image without 20.reputation

Comment: Ya i have tried using the same.  But i am confused with applying e^3t

Comment: 1/2{1/s  - s /(s^2 4)}

Comment: Ok got it... Thanks

Comment: You can ask  comment to be given as answer when it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Converted my comments into an answer:**

The procedure I would use is to find the first find the Laplace Transform of $\sin^2(t)$ using the identity $\sin^2(t)\equiv\dfrac{1-\cos(2t)}{2}$ and then apply the [first shifting theorem](https://www.mathalino.com/reviewer/advance-engineering-mathematics/first-shifting-property-laplace-transform), which states that:
$$\mathcal{L}\{e^{at}f(t)\}=F(s-a) \tag{1}$$
Where $F(s)=\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$. It is easy to prove the above using the [definition of the Laplace Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Formal_definition), which I leave as an exercise.

---

Letting $f(t)=\sin^2(t)$, we obtain for $F(s)$:
$$F(s)=\mathcal{L}\{\sin^2(t)\}=\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{L}\{1\}-\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{L}\{\cos(2t)\}=\frac{1}{2s}-\frac{s}{2(s^2+4)}=\frac{2}{s(s^2+4)}$$
Thus, it follows from the first shifting theorem that:
$$\mathcal{L}\{e^{3t}f(t)\}=F(s-3)=\frac{2}{(s-3)((s-3)^2+4)}=\frac{2}{(s-3)(s^2-6s+13)}$$